# How to set 'charset' for DatumWriter || write avro that contains arabic characters to HDFS

Tags: java, hdfs, avro

Some of the data contains value in Arabic format, and when the data is written, reader code/`hadoop fs -text` command shows `??` instead of Arabic characters.

**1) Writer**

```
// avro object is provided as SpecificRecordBase
Path path = new Path(pathStr);
DatumWriter<SpecificRecord> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsUri), conf); // HDFS File System

FSDataOutputStream outputStream = fs.create(path);
DataFileWriter<SpecificRecord> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter);

Schema schema = getSchema(); // method to get schema
dataFileWriter.setCodec(CodecFactory.snappyCodec());
dataFileWriter.create(schema, outputStream);
dataFileWriter.append(avroObject);
```

**2) Reader**

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FsInput in = new FsInput(new Path(hdfsFilePathStr), conf);
DatumReader<Row> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
DataFileReader<Row> dataFileReader = new DataFileReader<>(in, datumReader);
GenericRecord outputData = (GenericRecord) dataFileReader.iterator.next();
```

I've tried `hadoop fs -text {filePath}` command, there also the values in Arabic appear as `??`.

It will be really difficult to change the format in which data is written because there are numerous consumers of the same file.

Tried reading through `SpecificRecordBase`, still getting `??`.

**Edit**

Also tried these (in both reader and writer):

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("file.encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_16.displayName());
```

AND

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_16.displayName());
```

Doesn't help.

Comment: "it" shows. What exactly is "it"? Avro uses UTF8 for strings, so I'd say either the data is corrupted already at the input, or whatever you're using to view the data isn't showing UTF8 properly.

Comment: @Kayaman how can we change the charset? I've checked, and the avro object itself has the data in correct format.

** It = refers to the reader - either the Java code mentioned in the question or hdfs text command.

Comment: When you display the text with arabic  characters, are you sure that the font contains these characters? In java, such cha"missing" characters are usually displayed as ?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer yes, the avro object correctly displays the arabic values.

Comment: Maybe your terminal just doesn't show them correctly.

Comment: @Kayaman I suspected the same initially, but neither does the API that later consumes this (the API otherwise works fine with Arabic characters), or the Java code mentioned above that reads the avro files.

Comment: There really isn't any obvious point in the code shown where encoding problems could occur.

Comment: @Kayaman yes, I'm unable to figure out myself. The end result that I want is the reader to be able to fetch data from avro file and not get `??` instead of Arabic characters.

Comment: Go through the file with a hex editor to check the bytes. Then run a debugger and track what happens to the string values.

Comment: I did not exactly get you @Kayaman can you explain?

Comment: Open the file and check the binary values to see if the characters are corrupted in the file (this may require learning about the avro format and UTF8 if you're not fluent in it). If you verify that the characters in the file are corrupted it means something is wrong in the writing process. Then track the string values in a debugger to see what happens during the writing process to corrupt them. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, hire a consultant or something.

Comment: Got your point.

Comment: Apparently the issue appears only when writing to HDFS, if I use Local File System, then it works seamlessly. One solution is to change the String datatype to bytes in avro; currently I'm exploring having this fix in HDFS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, HDFS does not support a lot of non-english characters. To work around that, change the field from `String` to `bytes` in your avro schema.

To convert your value from `String` to `bytes`, use:

`ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`.

Then, while reading, to convert it back to String use:

`new String(byteData.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Rest of the code in your reader and writer stays the same.

Doing this, for English characters `hadooop fs -text` command will show proper text but for non-English characters it might show gibberish, but your reader will still be able to create the `UTF-8` String from `ByteBuffer`.